# Connecting to MySQL database within classes in object-oriented PHP

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo, crud

Forgive me for poor wording, I've only been learning PHP and MySQL for a few months, and I'm self taught.

Currently, I'm struggling a little with OOP concepts. What is best practice for connecting to the database within classes?

`config.php` includes a class named `DB` with a constructor that creates a database connection, and a set of functions that can be used to perform various operations on the database (CRUD).

Now, let's say I have the file `user.class.php` which contains a class named `User` . I want `User` to contain variables (such as `id` and `name` ) and functions (such as `login` and `logout` ) related to user accounts. This requires a database connection and use of the functions I defined in `DB` , but obviously I cannot use those functions in a different class.

What is the best way to do this? Options I have considered:

1. Having `User` extend `DB` (This is what I'm leaning towards, but I'm not sure if it's technically correct.)
2. Making `DB` a trait instead of a class, so I can use it in *all* the classes that require it. (Or if I go with option 1, I could just have all those classes extend `DB` , right? Which is better?)
3. Passing an instance of `DB` as a parameter to the `User` constructor function (Would this make sense? Would this even work? I feel like this is not the right answer, but I could be wrong.)

Comment: My vote is for Option 3. You only want ONE connection per script. So avoid anything that would have the potential to create more than one connection in any one script. Opt 1 and 2 would run that risk.

Comment: That's a very good question. but, actually 1 is least preferable, because, you know, a *user* is not a *database connection*. While 3 is actually the way to go, because a user can use a database connection as a *dependency*

Comment: I personally tend to go the route of defining one global database object, which my other classes can access, because I don't like having to pass it into the constructor every time. I think it really depends on your projects overall structure and your personal style. Keep in mind global objects tend to be frowned upon, I don't really use them for anything else.